# How do I get the API Key message to go away TinyMCE? (Django)

Tags: python, django, tinymce

I've included the TinyMCE editor into my program and it's showing up, but says I need to add a API key. I've tried doing this but can't figure out where:

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/<KEY>/tinymce/4/tinymce.min.js" referrerpolicy="origin"></script>
</head>
{% block content %}
    <div class="content-section">
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.media }}
            <fieldset class="form-group" id = #mytextarea>
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Add Law</legend>
                {{ form|crispy }}
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Finish</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

This is my form.html template.

Here is my settings.py:

```
TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
    'cleanup_on_startup': True,
    'custom_undo_redo_levels': 20,
    'selector': 'textarea',
    'theme': 'silver',
    'plugins': '''
            textcolor save link image media preview codesample contextmenu
            table code lists fullscreen  insertdatetime  nonbreaking
            contextmenu directionality searchreplace wordcount visualblocks
            visualchars code fullscreen autolink lists  charmap print  hr
            anchor pagebreak
            ''',
    'toolbar1': '''
            fullscreen preview bold italic underline | fontselect,
            fontsizeselect  | forecolor backcolor | alignleft alignright |
            aligncenter alignjustify | indent outdent | bullist numlist table |
            | link image media | codesample |
            ''',
    'toolbar2': '''
            visualblocks visualchars |
            charmap hr pagebreak nonbreaking anchor |  code |
            ''',
    'contextmenu': 'formats | link image',
    'menubar': True,
    'statusbar': True,
}

TINYMCE_JS_URL = 'https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/<KEY>/tinymce/5/tinymce.min.js'
```

and finally my models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
from tinymce.models import HTMLField

class Law(models.Model):
    identifier = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=400)
    definitions = models.TextField()
    content = HTMLField(blank=True, null=True)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    writer = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    signed = models.DateField()
    proposed = models.DateField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('law-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

I can't seem to figure out where to put my API key. I've tried everywhere and can't seem to figure out an area for it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can sign up for a free API key at [tiny.cloud](https://www.tiny.cloud/). Note that new accounts come with a 30-day trial of all of TinyMCE's commercial plugins, and trial access to Tiny's Support channel. After these thirty days, those commercial entitlements are removed, but the API key will continue to serve the open source, community edition of the Editor.

Once you have an API key, it goes in the place of `<KEY>` in the URL you call to load TinyMCE:

```
https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/<KEY>/tinymce/5/tinymce.min.js
```

For more information, check out:
https://www.tiny.cloud/blog/how-to-get-tinymce-cloud-up-in-less-than-5-minutes/

Note, that if you are still within your 30-day trial, you have access to Tiny's Support channel, whom can assist you with these and other matters relating to installing, configuring and utilizing Tiny Cloud in your projects.